# grouping of xml data using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is an xml I want to transform to below result using xsl. Any help please.This is some thing like windows directory structure.here the depth of the directory is dynamic.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<qc name="accounting" level="1">
    <qc name="fund" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_0" level="3"/>
    </qc>
</qc>
<qc name="asset_allocation" level="1">
    <qc name="fund" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_0" level="3"/>
    </qc>
</qc>
<qc name="asset_allocation" level="1">
    <qc name="fund" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_1" level="3"/>
    </qc>
</qc>
<qc name="credit_quality" level="1">
    <qc name="account" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_0" level="3"/>
    </qc>
</qc>
<qc name="credit_quality" level="1">
    <qc name="fund" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_0" level="3"/>
    </qc>
</qc>
<qc name="credit_quality" level="1">
    <qc name="v1_0" level="2"/>
</qc>
<qc name="credit_quality" level="1">
    <qc name="v2_0" level="2"/>
</qc>
<qc name="portfolio" level="1">
    <qc name="credit_quality" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_0" level="3"/>
    </qc>
</qc>
</root>
```

In above xml I have  with each level name. I want to group the same names at the same level.

Result:

```
<root>
<qc name="accounting" level="1">
    <qc name="fund" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_0" level="3"/>
    </qc>
</qc>
<qc name="asset_allocation" level="1">
    <qc name="fund" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_0" level="3"/>
        <qc name="v1_1" level="3"/>
    </qc>
</qc>
<qc name="credit_quality" level="1">
    <qc name="account" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_0" level="3"/>
    </qc>
    <qc name="fund" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_0" level="3"/>
    </qc>
    <qc name="v1_0" level="2"/>
    <qc name="v2_0" level="2"/>
</qc>
<qc name="portfolio" level="1">
    <qc name="credit_quality" level="2">
        <qc name="v1_0" level="3"/>
    </qc>
</qc>
 </root>
```

Comment: So where's the XSL you have so far?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use XSLT 2.0, do, and use the xsl:for-each-group instruction.

If you are stuck with XSLT 1.0, read up about Muenchian grouping.

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack using XSLT 1.0 and EXSLT functions could look like this. It's probably not the most elegant solution but it should work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions"
  xmlns:my="my-namespace"
  extension-element-prefixes="func"
  exclude-result-prefixes="my">

  <xsl:key name="qc-by-path" match="qc" use="my:path(.)"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="qc">
    <xsl:variable name="peers" select="key('qc-by-path', my:path(.))"/>
    <xsl:if test="generate-id(.)=generate-id($peers[1])">
      <qc name="{@name}" level="{@level}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$peers/qc"/>
      </qc>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <func:function name="my:path">
    <xsl:param name="qc"/>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$qc/parent::qc">
        <func:result select="concat(my:path($qc/parent::qc),'/',$qc/@name)"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <func:result select="$qc/@name"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>  
  </func:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```